# regular expression : group function

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I want to extract `newsletter_` and `_mon_gallery` from the phrase

```
002c2833d0-newsletter_20131028_mon_gallery
```

I tried with `([^\d-_]+){3,}`

```
002c2833d0-newsletter_20131028_mon_gallery
```

So i can check in  http://www.regexpal.com/ . it is visually separating the two entities `newsletter_` and `_mon_gallery`.

But the problem is i am not able to retrieve the matched values from group function.

```
import re
string='002c2833d0-newsletter_20131028_mon_enamour'
m=re.search('([^\d-]+){3,}',string)
print m.group()
```

i just get

```
newsletter_
```

Comment: I think you want `groups()` with an `s`.

Comment: Can you please tag this as Python? A language tag is relevant here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.search()` is designed to return the *first* match. You want

```
m = re.findall('[^\d-]{3,}',string)
```

Note that I've edited your regex to remove the nested quantifiers (can you say "[catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)"?) and the unnecessary (and harmful if repeated) capturing group.

Comment: what about if i want to exclude some string at the same time: 
for eg: `fa99bdbfbc-newsletter_20130904_wed_furniture_runway` and i want `bdbfbc` not to be selected. the pattern is that every thing at the start with the mixture of digit in it should be prevented.

Comment: This requires a bit more info. If "everything at the start with digits" is forbidden, then we need a character that will reliably act as a delimiter (`_`, for example?); otherwise nothing could ever match after a digits has been present in the string. Alternatively, can you restrict the set of characters that are allowed to match?

Comment: Yes i Just restricted it. `string_modified=re.sub('^[\d.\w.]+-','',string)`
its a fixed pattern that string starts with it and has `'-'` following it.

Comment: OK, that's a good idea as well, although `\w` already contains `\d`. And unless you also want to allow actual dots in this starting "word", you don't need it in the character class (let alone twice). So `r'\w+-'` might be enough, or `r'[\w.]+-'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall), but you have to slightly change the regular expression from this:

```
([^\d-]+){3,}
```

to this:

```
([^\d-]{3,})
```

(In general, there's no need to have both `+` and `{3,}` together as the latter implies the first.)

```
>>> re.findall('[^\d-]{3,}', string)
['newsletter_', '_mon_enamour']
```